# c++ boost locale - generator throws runtime_error with "Invalid file format" message

Tags: c++, boost, locale

I try to reproduce the example of [boost locale documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/locale/doc/html/messages_formatting.html) with this piece of code :

```cpp
#include <boost/locale.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace boost::locale;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   generator gen;

   // Specify location of dictionaries
   gen.add_messages_path("./languages");
   gen.add_messages_domain("hello");

   // Generate locales and imbue them to iostream
   locale::global(gen("es_ES"));
   cout.imbue(locale());

   // Display a message using current system locale
   cout << translate("Hello World") << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

I have generated this `hello.mo` file with xgettext and put it in a folder `./languages/es_ES/LC_MESSAGES` :

```
# SOME DESCRIPTIVE TITLE.
# Copyright (C) YEAR THE PACKAGE'S COPYRIGHT HOLDER
# This file is distributed under the same license as the PACKAGE package.
# FIRST AUTHOR <EMAIL@ADDRESS>, YEAR.
#
#, fuzzy
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: PACKAGE VERSION\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2022-01-13 17:30+0100\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"Language: \n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=CHARSET\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"

#: test.cpp:95
msgid "Hello World"
msgstr "Hola a todos"
```

When I run the code, the line `locale::global(gen("es_ES"));` throws a `std::runtime_error` with this message : "Invalid file format". Does it mean that there is an error in the .mo file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to compile the .po file... `xgettext` generates a .po text file which needs to be compiled into a .mo file. This can be done with `msgfmt` :

`msgfmt hello.po -o hello.mo`